# Lock-in amplifiers, signal averaging and signal post-processing

Tags: amplifier, signal-processing

I would like to know about what are the benefits of using a lock-in amplifier. I have read that they basically consist on multiplying a signal by a reference which switches the frequency to DC. Then the signal is integrated to remove the noise thanks to their randomness.

My question is: what is the difference of this with respect to simply averaging the signal in an oscilloscope?

Additionally, reading on DSP Lock-in amplifiers, is it not equivalent to perform some post-processing techniques on a recorded signal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Averaging a DC signal to reduce noise doesn't get rid of:

- DC offsets of amplifier chain
- Thermally-induced offset voltages

  Furthermore, noise tends not to be "white" at low frequencies. (Noise of amplifiers includes a 1/f effect).

Lock-in amplifier avoids all these pitfalls. You can place the reference frequency where the amplifier chain adds least noise.

---

Does post-processing include a recording of the reference signal as well as the actual signal? If so, then post-processing could be done, equivalent to a lock-in.

If you only have one channel recorded (actual noisy signal) then post-processing isn't equivalent to lock-in processing. A lock-in is a *tracking bandpass filter* while post-processing without a reference frequency is a *fixed-frequency bandpass filter*.
When a lock-in is set to very long time-constant, you have a very narrow bandwidth filter indeed - it is difficult to maintain phase coherency over such a long period. A tracking filter helps greatly when the reference frequency is not stable.
For example, an optical beam chopper motor is very difficult to maintain at a stable rotational rate, resulting in the reference frequency wandering. This instability puts a limit on how narrow the filter bandwidth can be used with a fixed-frequency filter.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: what is the difference of this with respect to simply averaging the signal in an oscilloscope?

They do different things.  A lock in amplifier enables you to obtain an extremely small detection bandwidth (thousands to trillions of times narrower than the center frequency of a modulated signal), enabling extraction of a narrowband signal from broadband noise.  Averaging just increases SNR and will not help you extract one signal from another.

In addition, since a lock in amplifier is coherent, it has a 3dB sensitivity advantage over incoherent detection, so even at equal bandwidth it will have higher SNR than averaging.

> Additionally, reading on DSP Lock-in amplifiers, is it not equivalent to perform some post-processing techniques on a recorded signal?

You can implement a lock in amplifier using a two channel ADC to record both the clock and signal and then perform the mixing stages in post processing, and for many applications this is the most efficient option.  However, if you perform the mixing digitally, the ADC has to have enough dynamic range to record both the signal and then noise as well as enough bandwidth to sample both, which can be a problem if your signal is much, much weaker than the noise or your bandwidth is very high.  In that case, using an analog mixer may be a better approach.